# How to use data sent via POST in GET request in express JS

Tags: node.js, api, express, post, get

I need to listen on exposed port:5000 for JSON input sent via an HTTP POST to "/test", e.g. "http://localhost:5000/test"

I am not able to figure out how to get the data. Please help!

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/test', function(request, response){
      // need to get data here
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log("server started");
  });
```

Comment: Well, you have to store the data somewhere e.g. a database, file or in-memory in order to return it on the get request. The simplest (not really useful, but it shows the principle) thing would be to assign the data to a global variable and then just return that when you receive the get request.

Comment: put it in a database or memory, `response.send(dataFromDBOrMemory);`

Comment: the post request is not send in the code. The code simply needs to listen to the request that arrives at "/checksum". @Mushroomator

Comment: As I said, you will need to get the data from somewhere. Typically that's a file or a database. As far as I understand you get the data in the POST request, so where do you store that data? On the get request you need to access that data store, get the data and return it.